# Can I create a manifold in two steps?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I know I can create a manifold by taking taking some smooth function $F:\mathbb{R}^{n+m} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and saying that e.g. $M = F^{-1}(0) \setminus crit(F)$ (where $crit(F)$ are the critical points of $F$ i.e. the points where the jacobian of $F$ is not surjective) is a $n$-manifold. But, can I do it like this instead:

Say I have two smooth functions: $F:\mathbb{R}^{n+m+k} \to \mathbb{R}^{k}$ and $G:\mathbb{R}^{n+m+k} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and then do:

$$M = F^{-1}(0) \setminus crit(F)$$
$$N = (M \cap G^{-1}(0)) \setminus crit(G)$$

resulting in a $N$ being an $n$-manifold? I feel like I should be able to do something like this, but my instinct I need to change the way I calculate the Jacobian of $G$ when creating $N$. I'm just not sure what to do then. Do I try to re-write $G$ has some function $\hat{G}:M \to \mathbb{R^n}$ and then calculate its Jacobian?

Comment: What does your notation $F^0$ mean? Is this what the rest of us would write as $F^{-1}(0)$? You need a transversality condition on $F$ and $G$ in order to guarantee that $F=G=0$ will be smooth, even with the proper rank conditions on them individually.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, sorry. I fixed it to $F^{-1}(0)$. What is the transversality condition? Does it make it equivalent to $H^{-1}(0) \setminus crit(H)$ where $H(x) = (F(x) \, G(x))^t$?

Comment: Yes, you want to apply the regular value theorem to $(F,G)\colon\Bbb R^{n+m+k}\to\Bbb R^{m+k}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin yeah, I know I can do that. But I was hoping to do it with two steps. Is this] the transversality condition you mean?  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_(mathematics))

Comment: You do not want to do it in two steps. To do that, you will need the derivative of $G|_M$ and that is almost impossible to calculate. Are you going to find local coordinates on $M$ around every point? Trust me. You do not want to think about it this way.

Comment: Gotcha. Okay, I'll do it the $(F, G)$ way. I was just trying to avoid some annoying calculations regarding the rank of the jacobian of $(F, G)$. I suppose I was avoiding annoying calculations by replacing them with even more annoying ones. Thanks!

Comment: Even when $M$ is the unit sphere, trying to differentiate the restriction of an arbitrary smooth function to $M$ is a royal pain.